# Asterisk - Transfer call record not saving in database and recording filename not overriding

Tags: asterisk

Before transferring call, Audio is recording correctly and overriding filename with custom filename format. Example `FULLDATE_CUSTPHONE_INGROUP_TEST_AGENT`

> Here is the screenshot 1

[image]

But, When I transfer the call to InGroup. The file is recording, but not in exact format. And the record files are not saving in database.

> Here is another screenshot for `recording filename` after Transferring Call to InGroup

[image]

My question is, how can I rename the filename with custom format?

Like `FULLDATE_CUSTPHONE_INGROUP_TEST_AGENT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rename file while it do writing.

You can stop recording, start with new filename.

Also you can add hangup header or read via AMI hangup event, after that move file as you wish.

Comment: Can I change `transfer call` recording `file name` before writing to directory?

Comment: You can change name in dialplan before start of mixmonitor.

Comment: So, Can I follow this url http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/mixmonitor.html for dialplan? Or any url please. Because i am very beginner

Comment: If you are very beginner, start your run from ORelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony"

Comment: And I really don't understand why someone downvote this Question. :( :( 
 Thank you very much for your information. (y)